# When to use SharePoint SPServices instead of REST

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spservices, sharepoint-rest-api

Can anybody let me know

- When to use `SPServices` instead of `REST` and when to user REST instead of SPServices,
- Which one is faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SOAP Web Services speak XML`. That is, we send XML in our requests and we get XML in the responses. These days many developers feel those services are `chatty` and that `XML is bloated`. I’m not so sure that’s really the case, but I can go along with it.

When we receive XML in the response from a SOAP call to the server, we have to parse it apart so that we can use the data. The most common operation that people use in `SPServices` is `GetListItems`, which allows us to pull list data from the server to the client.

With the `SOAP Web Services, XML is our only option`. There’s no way to request anything else. `REST, on the other hand, is usually used to request JSON`.

To bring SPServices more into the modern way of doing things, I added a `function in 0.7.1 called SPXmlToJson` and then another in `2014.01 called SPGetListItemsJson`. These two functions make it easy – really easy – to convert XML to JSON. You don’t have to know much about either method of storing data to get JSON back.

With REST we can still choose to get XML in the response, but we also have the option to request that the server send us JSON. Because JSON is a text representation of JavaScript objects, the conversion is much more straightforward, with just a call to `$.parseJSON` (assuming you’re using jQuery).

JSON is preferable because it doesn’t require much – if any – translation when we want to use it. You may already be converting the XML you get back with `SPServices` calls into `JSON`, either manually or with a call to `SPXmlToJson` or `SPGetListItemsJson`.

[Reference](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Beginning-SharePoint-development-with-KoSp-Knockout-for-SharePoint-REST-API-and-SP-Services.aspx)

**For Best & Good Answer** [Should I learn SPServices for SharePoint online or should I move to REST?](https://www.quora.com/Should-I-learn-SPServices-for-SharePoint-online-or-should-I-move-to-REST)